# How to add an image in a for loop in java

Tags: java, swing

This is for a hangman game

```
public static String letterGuessed;
public static String[] word = {"fuzzy","chess","elephant","cheesecake","charger","laptop","relevance","funnybone"};
public static int ran;
public static JLabel jl = new JLabel();

 public void wordGenerator(){


    int max = 8;
    int wordLength;
    int counter = 0;

    int min = 0;
    ran = (int)(Math.random()* (max - min +1) + min);

    wordLength = word[ran].length();

    while (counter <= wordLength){

        lblWord.setText( lblWord.getText() + "_ ");

        counter++;

    }

}
public void getLetter(){

    letterGuessed = txtLetterGuess.getText();


}



public void rightOrWrongGuess() {

    if (word[ran].contains(letterGuessed)){

        //lblWord.replace.

    } else {

        //PICTURE CHANGE


    }

    lblGuessedLetters.setText(lblGuessedLetters.getText() + "_ " + letterGuessed);

}
private void btnGuessLetterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   


    getLetter();
    rightOrWrongGuess();

    for (int i=0;i<=6;i++) {
        if (!word[ran].contains(letterGuessed)) {
            lblPicture.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Pic\\hangman" + i + ".jpg")); 

        }
    }
```

So I tried to use the counter to upload a different picture each time they guess the wrong letter. There is only 6 pictures, the last being the full hangman. The `i` or `counter` doesn't seem to work.

I think that I would not get a rapid succession of pictures because they would have to click the button each time.
Thanks.

Comment: I'd try building the string for the path first and placing it in a variable, and using the variable to create the ImageIcon object. What error are you getting specifically?

Comment: A couple problems. This loop iterates 7 times due to <= 6.  It will also rapidly load all 6 images in succession

Comment: Why doesn't it seem to work?

Comment: Use some simple print statements to check whether or not your counter is working. In the loop print out i, in the if statement print the picture location, then see what actually is not working as expected.'

Comment: Im getting no picture

Comment: @user3746363 Is the file path correct? Does that if statement ever evaluate to true? is btnGuessLetterActionPerformed ever called?

Comment: Yes this is just part of the program. I don't know if i should be getting a rapid succession of pictures. I thought they would only come once the user has clicked on the button

Comment: @user3746363 If that is the case, then we are not given enough information. Many of the variables are unexplained, as well as the methods.  I see a for loop that loops through 6 pictures based on some condition that I have no idea what it means.

Comment: ill upload the rest there is still many bugs on other stuff. I'm just trying to get the pictures to change

Comment: @user3746363 Get the other stuff working first. Gotta build the house before the city :)

Comment: There i uploaded the stuff that is relevant and that works

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to use a for loop, it makes no sense, because you'll be looping through **all** the images, **immediately** with each button push. So if the user pushes the button once, the six images will be swapped immediately, and since it's done on the Swing event thread, they will not be seen at all, except for the last image. Press the button again, and zip, the same thing happens.

No you want to simply increment an int counter variable inside of your actionPerformed, and then use that int to change the image once, not in a for loop.

e.g. in pseudocode,

```
private void btnGuessLetterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                         
  get the letter selected
  if the letter is correct, 
     update the guess word display to show the new letter in the word
  end if
  else // the letter is incorrect
     incorrectGuessCount++;
     if incorrectGuessCount == max, game over, show whole image
     else 
        setIcon to the hangmanImageIconList.get(incorrectGuessCount)
     end else
  end else 
}
```

---

Also, load all the images into an ArrayList at the beginning of the program not on button press.

Comment: This helps. My last dilemma is changing the image. There is six: hangman1.jpg, hangman2.jpg, hangman3.jpg, etc.  I want to change the number.

Comment: @user3746363: are you asking a question in the comment above? If so, it isn't clear at all what your question is.

Comment: in relation to my code. Thats what i was attempting to do with my for loop

Comment: OK, but you understand now why it's a bad idea, why the for loop has no business being there, right?

Comment: yes i just don't know how to get each picture to come up after each wrong guess

Comment: @user3746363: I have already explained how to do this in my answer and pseudocode above. If the information in the answer confuses you, then please ask a specific question for clarification. The more specific your question, the greater our chances of helping you.

Comment: o okay i see it now. Thank you very much for your help